# node/js es6 "class" inherit prototype (chain) from function

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, stream

Is it possible to inerhit the prototype chain from a function in a es6 class definition?

```js
const { PassThrough } = require("stream");
const duplexer = require("duplexer3");


class Interface {

    constructor(obj, options) {

        options = Object.assign({
            decodeStrings: false,
            autoClose: false,
            objectMode: true
        }, options);

        let reader = new PassThrough(options);
        let writer = new PassThrough(options);


        // use duplex stream as prototype
        this = duplexer(options, reader, writer);



        Object.assign(this, obj);

    };

};


const iface = new Interface({
    _id: "60891a02256c0c7931395c48",
    settings: {
        port: 8080,
        host: "127.0.0.1"
    }
});
```

```js
this = duplexer(options, reader, writer);
```

Gives me the error:

```
        this = duplexer(options, reader, writer);
        ^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at Object.compileFunction (vm.js:344:18)
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1048:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1082:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

If i use, `extends` & `super`, it works, but i have the properties of the duplexer stream on the Interface object, but i want to "hide" them, upper in the prototype chain.

```js
class Interface extends duplexer {

    constructor(obj, options) {

        options = Object.assign({
            decodeStrings: false,
            autoClose: false,
            objectMode: true
        }, options);

        let reader = new PassThrough(options);
        let writer = new PassThrough(options);

        super(options, reader, writer)
        Object.assign(this, obj);

    };

};
```

Not sure, if this is possible or i understand it correct, but when i inerhit some properties from a other class/object, they "stay" in its origin object scope, and when i want to access them the engine "looks" upwards till a propertie is found, if not, its `undefined`.

My goal is to have my clean "Interace" object instance, with properties i pass to my consctrutor and still be able to use the node.js stream specific methods (read/write/etc.)

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I found a workaround with a Proxy object:

```js
class Root {
    constructor() {
        this.root = true;
    }
    rootMethod() {
        console.log("i am root");
    }
}


class Parent extends Root {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.parent = true;
    }
    parentMethod() {
        console.log("i am parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.child = true;
    }
    childMethod() {
        console.log("i am child")
    }
}


class Interface {
    constructor() {
        this.settings = {
            host: "0.0.0.0",
            port: 8030
        }
    }
}

const root = new Root();
const parent = new Parent();
const child = new Child();
const iface = new Interface();


const proxy = new Proxy(child, {
    get: function (target, prop) {

        if (target[prop]) {
            return target[prop];
        } else {
            return iface[prop];
        }

    }
});


//console.log(root, root.rootMethod);
//console.log(parent, parent.parentMethod);
//console.log(child, child.childMethod);

console.log(proxy.settings, proxy.rootMethod)
```

This checks if a property exists on the proxied object, if not, try to access the property on the hidden object.

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance - just have a `.#duplex` member and delegate the stream interface to it? (Or better - use async iterators instead :D)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for your reply. Can you give me a description/link/example for "composition"? I heard it for the first time... This seems so simple but i cant figure it out, that drives me insane

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#:~:text=Composition%20over%20inheritance%20(or%20composite,than%20inheritance%20from%20a%20base

Comment: I understand the concept, but i cant put code together where my problem is solved. All i achieve is that the "Interface" scope, is polluted with the parent/duplexer methods/properties.I dont know why... https://pastebin.com/raw/ihGvi1aX was the closest i can do, but here is the class name "Stream" displayed in `console.log`, which is not so nice... I dont get it, in the plain js objects its work too...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum What do you think about my workaround, with a proxy object?

Comment: Sorry - I think it's complicated and hard to debug :D

Answer (score 1):

It's a sure thing. You just need to amend the prototype of the subclass's prototype , and there you go.

Check out the code:

```js
class Interface {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(Interface.prototype, Duplex.prototype)
const instance = new Interface
// you are able to call method from Duplex
instance.someMethodFromDuplex()
```

Comment: Can you give me a "working" example? I have to pass arguments to the `duplexer` function. This is not the "Duplex" stream from node.js internals. I dont understand your code snippet enough to extend it the way i need it. The prototype chain here: https://medium.com/developers-arena/javascript-classes-inheritance-and-prototype-chaining-es5-and-es6-way-4b8e9416702b is what im talking about. I want the result from "Inheritance — the ES5 way" but with the duplexer method from my snippet

Comment: In fact, the **extends** keyword exaclty meets your demand. But I see you want to ' hide ' the properties from Duplexer, this requirement looks a bit unusual. What's the imperative reason about that ? Maybe we can find some alternative way.

Comment: The Interface instance (with it properties) should be sent over a API and displayed  in the frontend, when the scope is littered with properties from the super/parent class its messy and not clean. I mean, it works with standard js objects/functions too... Take a loook here: https://pastebin.com/raw/ihGvi1aX this is close, but as you see in the `console.log` it says its a "Stream" object, and not my "Interface" object, is there a way to "change" the name that is beeing displayed?

Comment: Based on the situation you described, I do think a better approach is that you may implement a class‘s function which returns an object that explicit contains something you want to send over API, and then use this function's returned value instead of passing the whole instance to your AJAX method.  This way is pretty clear and declarative.  By the way, in your snippet **console.log**  shows a **Interface** object, which is a correct result apparently.

Comment: in node it shows a "Stream" Object. In the Browser i dont see a class name. Can you post a screenshot? Edit: In Chromium it shows indeed a "Interface" Object/name. Thats interesting...

Comment: I editet my question and have added a workaround with a proxy object, what do you think about it?

Comment: I think this is not the case for using Proxy.